# embed string into html with razor condition statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Iterating a foreach loop and trying to embed some string with razor, to achive this I tried code below;

```
<span class="label label-sm label-@item.isCorrect?@String.Format("success"):@String.Format("danger"))">
                                        @item.CorrectAnswer
                                    </span>
```

how it looks like in browser;

```
<span class="label label-sm label-class?success:danger)">
                                            A
                                        </span>
```

I just expected;

```
<span class="label label-sm label-success">
                                            A
                                        </span>
```

what should i do?

Comment: try @(item.isCorrect?@String.Format("success"):@String.Format("danger"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were nearly there... just a missing bracket... i've put the below in one of my pages with my model and it works.

```
<span class="label label-sm label-@(item.isCorrect ? string.Format("success"):@String.Format("danger"))">
    @item.CorrectAnswer
</span>
```

Hope that helps.